# obtener el contenido de un array para luego comparar

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-8

Necesito obtener el contenido de un array para luego compararlo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo puedo obtenerlos por separado?

intente hacer un foreach pero solo me daba el segundo id (2).

Debo compararlo en la siguiente consulta:

```
$producto = Productos::where('id', 1)->get();
```

Comment: Asignalo a una variable y podrás acceder por el índice, por en `$array[0]` o `$array[1]`

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ pero si necesito todos osea el 0 y el 1 ???

Comment: A que te refieres cuando en la pregunta dices "¿Cómo puedo obtenerlos por separado?"

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ   me refiero a extraerlos del array al id 1,2  para luego poder hacer un foreach de los productos  con mi consulta $productos

Comment: No me queda claro que es lo que quieres lograr. Si quieres consultar los Product que tengan como id a alguno de los elementos del array podrías usar `whereIn` en lugar de sólo `where` y pasarle el array directamente, o sea `$producto = Productos::whereIn('id', $array)->get();` te daría los mismos resultados que `$producto = Productos::where('id', $array[0])->orWhere('id', $array[1])->get();`

Answer (score 0):

Supongamos que tu Array sea

```
$array = [
    1,
    2
];
```

Para acceder a las posiciones solo pones

```
$array[0] //Esto imprime 1 
$array[1] //Esto imprime 2
```

Comment: necesito los 2 no uno solo en especifico

Comment: Entonces lo que buscas es hacer un whereIn('id',$array)->get()